# Open office files in Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, ms-office

I want to open office documents, like Word, Excel and PowerPoint, from my BlackBerry app. I am able to download the files from the server, but I am not sure how to open them.

Comment: hello Jithesh G, sir I am working for downloading a pdf file from a url. Can you please suggest me with some snippet how to code for this task.

Answer (score 1):

On BlackBerry devices there is a trial version of DataViz DocsToGo pre-installed. And you can use DocsToGo Word to open Word documents, DocsToGo Excel to open excel documents, etc.